# Nomenclature of unusual nitrogen functional group

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I am trying to create a proflavine derivative containing a 1,2,4-oxadiazole-5-one functional group, the first step produces an interesting functional group that I have no idea how to name:

$$\ce{[Pro]-NH-CH=N-OH}$$

I am trying to find literature on the above functional group so I can analyze proton NMR to see if I have actual created the above molecule.

Comment: Does the $\ce{-NH-}$ group in $\ce{[Pro]-NH-CH=N-OH}$ correspond to one of the $\ce{-NH2}$ groups of proflavine?

Comment: The HC=N-OH part is usually called an aldoxime, so I might say a "formamide aldoxime" if I were describing it to someone.

Comment: IUPAC aside, such compounds are usually called **amidoximes**.

Answer (score 8):

According to *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069),* the preferred IUPAC name of the compound $\ce{H2N-CH=NH}$ is **methanimidamide.** The name **formimidamide** may be used in general nomenclature. The name **formamidine** is no longer recommended.

The letter locants ‘*N*’ and ‘*N*'’ are used to differentiate among the different nitrogen atoms. Thus, the compound $\ce{R-NH-CH=N-OH}$ would be named as *N*'-hydroxy-*N*-…methanimidamide.